# TypeScript getter required when creating instance with plain object

Tags: javascript, typescript

Lets say I have a TypeScript class with a property called `birthDate` and 3 getters based on this property: `year`, `month` and `day`.

```
class User {
    birthDate: Date;
    
    get month(): number {
        return this.birthDate.getMonth();
    }
    
    get year(): number {
        return this.birthDate.getFullYear();
    }

    get day(): number {
        return this.birthDate.getDay();
    }
}
```

I can instantiate an `User`, set a `birthDate` and use the getters normally.

```
const user = new User();
user.birthDate = new Date();
console.log(user.year, user.month, user.day);
```

But, obviously, I can't set a year directly because I have only a getter (and not a setter)

```
// this does not work as expected
user.year = 2022
```

On the other hand, when I try to define an `User` with a plain object the TypeScript compiler generates an error saying that I have missing properties (`year`, `month` and `day`):

```
// this does not works... why?
const user: User = {
    birthDate: new Date()
}
```

My question is: why should I define these properties in the plain object since they are only getters? How can I create `User`s using plain objects in this case?

Working code [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictPropertyInitialization=false&ssl=20&ssc=2&pln=18&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAECqEFMBO0DeAoaXoCMCWSALgBYAiYhCAXNOZQNybZNYDmCh0AtgPYB2JABQBKGnwCuXHMjQtsWJB3FI%200EnggA6fETIUEm9oQCy-IcMbyAvnLlHoATwRgkIsZOkoM8%20YsLLVdS0dEjoDIwAxcRAQAE1nVws5GzsOaAATMAc3aAkpGW8fBSUVNWINbQJQ-UMOcmyk63QUgHoW6AB3YgcyjQyeBBg%20Hk4OniQAawh0YH4ITnFEJBp4GQBeWXkQvUoxBA7afRFm9Bm5haWAJmgNvn24JZFGReRLyt0wm9z7sKf0Nt6MHSAyGI064ym0Eg0AQAA8AA4IYCUdLoF5IN68ATEL4ARgADPQgA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is: why should I define these properties in the plain object since they are only getters?

Because your type says that read-only `year`, `month`, and `day` properties will exist on `User` objects, but there aren't any on the object you're trying to assign to a variable of type `User`.

> How can I create Users using plain objects in this case?

By providing the getters:

```typescript
const user: User = {
    birthDate: new Date(),
    get month(): number {
        return user.birthDate.getMonth();
    },
    get year(): number {
        return user.birthDate.getFullYear();
    },
    get day(): number {
        return user.birthDate.getDay();
    },
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictPropertyInitialization=false#code/MYGwhgzhAECqEFMBO0DeAoaXoCMCWSALgBYAiYhCAXNOZQNybZNYDmCh0AtgPYB2JABQBKGnwCuXHMjQtsWJB3FI+0EnggA6fETIUEm9oQCy-IcMbyAvnLlHoATwRgkIsZOkoM8+YsLLVdS0dEjoDIwAxcRAQAE1nVws5GzsOaAATMAc3aAkpGW8fBSUVNWINbQJQ-UMOcmyk63QU4H4ITnFEJBp4GQBeWXkQvUoxBAB3Wn0RABp0VM5eAWIcvM9Boug-AOhO5ErdMNqTMxXG7Cs5+QXHBNWPArlfEtU9pAPqymOomPiXEUsFzmN0yDXc+S8T2w21Kbw+I3CdSyAOSzUYQA)

But using a constructor function instead seems reasonable, so you can reuse the getters on the prototype.

For completeness: You could also do it by having the raw object inherit from a prototype with those getters on; that's probably best wrapped up as a function:

```typescript
interface User {
    birthDate: Date;
    readonly month: number;
    readonly year: number;
    readonly day: number;
}

const UserGetters: Partial<User> = {
    get month(): number {
        return this.birthDate!.getMonth();
    },
    get year(): number {
        return this.birthDate!.getFullYear();
    },
    get day(): number {
        return this.birthDate!.getDay();
    }
};

function makeUser(init: Pick<User, "birthDate">): User {
    return Object.assign(Object.create(UserGetters), init);
}
const user = makeUser({birthDate: new Date()})
console.log(user.year); // 2022 (at the moment)
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictPropertyInitialization=false&ssl=8&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#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)

(I cheated slightly there with non-null assertions, since I knew the `makeUser` function wouldn't allow `birthDate` to be unspecified or `null`.)

Some folks don't like constructor functions but do like prototypes, so that's an option for them.

Answer (score 2):

When you write

```js
const user: User = {
    birthDate: new Date()
}
```

you do *not* create a `User` object. You just create an object with a property `birthDate`. This object does not fulfill the interface implied by the declaration of `User` since it doesn't have the properties `month`, `year` and `day`.

---

Do you know that Javascript doesn't really have classes? It only has objects. In pure old Javascript, where the wasn't a `class` declaration, one wrote

```js
function User(birthDate) {
    this.birthDate = birthDate;
}

User.prototype.getYear = function () {
    return this.birthDate.getYear();
}

User.prototype.getMonth = function () {
    return this.birthDate.getMonth();
}

User.prototype.getDay = function () {
    return this.birthDate.getDay();
}

var user = new User(new Date());
```

A function, here `User()` could serve as a constructor, and when calling it with `new` an object was created using the class' `prototype` object as a prototype (actually, it's chained via the object's `__proto__` property).

The `class` declaration is merely syntactic sugar for the old pattern.

Answer (score 1):

The keyword here is `new`. In your first example you're actually instancing a `User`. In your second example you're merely creating an object that *looks* like a User (i.e. has all the attributes of a User).

You can create an object that looks like a user by providing all the attributes/getters/etc. However it's important to understand what the ramifications of this are. Note how the constructors are different.

```
class User {
    birthDate: Date;
    
    get month(): number {
        return this.birthDate.getMonth();
    }
    
    get year(): number {
        return this.birthDate.getFullYear();
    }

    get day(): number {
        return this.birthDate.getDay();
    }
}

const user1 = new User();
user1.birthDate = new Date(2010, 10, 22);
console.log("Constructor Name:" + user1.constructor.name); //prints "Constructor Name: User":


const user2: User = {
    birthDate: new Date(2010, 10, 22),
    get month(): number {
        return this.birthDate.getMonth();
    },
    get year(): number {
        return this.birthDate.getFullYear();
    },
    get day(): number {
        return this.birthDate.getDay();
    },
}
console.log("Constructor Name:" + user2.constructor.name); //prints "Constructor Name: Object"
```

[Typescript playground demonstrating](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECqEFMBO0DeBYAUNH0BGAlkgC4AWAImMQgFzSXUDcWu0LuA5gsdALYD2AOzIAKAJR1BAV155kadqxxJuUpIOhkCEAHSESFKgh1diAWSGixzbLgC%20itrZynoATwRgk4yTLkoMZyUVYjUNLV19MgZjUwAxKRAQAE1Pb2tHB0xHVwATMDcfaGlZeUClXBCwzVJtPSJooxNuSkKMoKysrGAhCB4pRCQARmgAXmKEAHc4QfEbAeQh%20oMYsYnpmJEAJgAGIZ2AGmh9o62t9p7BCH4QYxB%20DhEAIgBhXuIkKWBifhQAOTAvFoT2gAGpoAthjpLn1Pt9fjpBICENZoAB6NEAByQBGEMFe7zhP3%20yLo8GQTxoWG67whgy2ZMGa3KuCihmokim9CM2z2h2O-LOYgOOW4fEspCKJX8CiCrCq6hqdTZMWa5glc0yIqCrg8XilfjKjnlqkVEWWjWoaoSSVS%20varDs2tYeQKBtKAWNlVN4VqkQa7NiLTdDvs2qyMJudwezzeVw%20X2J0ABQJoIPBkK20MJiYRSKBqIx2NxxHxcdhuZJqegAHk8AArBDfJ5AA)